# liquibase generateChangeLog error with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, liquibase

Is it possible to generate change log from existing MongoDB database?

❯ liquibase generateChangeLog

```
[2021-04-05 11:01:31] INFO [liquibase.integration] No Liquibase Pro license key supplied. Please set liquibaseProLicenseKey on command line or in liquibase.properties to use Liquibase Pro features.
Liquibase Community 4.3.2 by Datical
Starting Liquibase at 11:01:31 (version 4.3.2 #44 built at 2021-03-23 14:01+0000)
[2021-04-05 11:01:31] INFO [com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log] Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
BEST PRACTICE: The changelog generated by diffChangeLog/generateChangeLog should be inspected for correctness and completeness before being deployed.
[2021-04-05 11:01:31] INFO [com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log] Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server localhost:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:70)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:669)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:645)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:64)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:79)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65)
        ... 3 more

Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.ClassCastException: class liquibase.ext.mongodb.database.MongoConnection cannot be cast to class liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection (liquibase.ext.mongodb.database.MongoConnection and liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
For more information, please use the --logLevel flag
[2021-04-05 11:01:31] SEVERE [liquibase.integration] Unexpected error running Liquibase: java.lang.ClassCastException: class liquibase.ext.mongodb.database.MongoConnection cannot be cast to class liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection (liquibase.ext.mongodb.database.MongoConnection and liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class liquibase.ext.mongodb.database.MongoConnection cannot be cast to class liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection (liquibase.ext.mongodb.database.MongoConnection and liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:251)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:1542)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.lambda$run$0(Main.java:367)
        at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:160)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:159)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:138)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:366)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main$1.run(Main.java:196)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:169)
        at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:145)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:196)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:158)
Caused by: liquibase.command.CommandExecutionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class liquibase.ext.mongodb.database.MongoConnection cannot be cast to class liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection (liquibase.ext.mongodb.database.MongoConnection and liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:24)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.doGenerateChangeLog(CommandLineUtils.java:249)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class liquibase.ext.mongodb.database.MongoConnection cannot be cast to class liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection (liquibase.ext.mongodb.database.MongoConnection and liquibase.database.jvm.JdbcConnection are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.getDatabaseCatalogNames(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:144)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.CatalogSnapshotGenerator.snapshotObject(CatalogSnapshotGenerator.java:35)
        at liquibase.snapshot.jvm.JdbcSnapshotGenerator.snapshot(JdbcSnapshotGenerator.java:65)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorChain.snapshot(SnapshotGeneratorChain.java:49)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.include(DatabaseSnapshot.java:315)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.init(DatabaseSnapshot.java:100)
        at liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot.<init>(DatabaseSnapshot.java:59)
        at liquibase.snapshot.JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.<init>(JdbcDatabaseSnapshot.java:38)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:215)
        at liquibase.snapshot.SnapshotGeneratorFactory.createSnapshot(SnapshotGeneratorFactory.java:188)
        at liquibase.command.core.DiffCommand.createReferenceSnapshot(DiffCommand.java:222)
        at liquibase.command.core.DiffCommand.createDiffResult(DiffCommand.java:144)
        at liquibase.command.core.GenerateChangeLogCommand.run(GenerateChangeLogCommand.java:62)
        at liquibase.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:19)
        ... 13 more
```

Liquibase properties:

changeLogFile: _changelog.xml

url: mongodb://localhost:27017/test?authSource=admin

username: xxx

password: xxx

logLevel: info

Is there any configuration that I am missing?

Comment: Looks like this might not be a supported command for this liquibase extension: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-mongodb/issues/119

Answer (score 1):

Currently, generatechangelog using the liquibase-mongodb extension is not supported.  I am using this [issue](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-mongodb/issues/119) as a reference.

However, you can request the feature [here](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-mongodb/issues).